# using php preg_match to validate float values

Tags: php, preg-match, floating

Using php (preg_match) to validate if a variable is float.
Been searching online but still have not found the one that i need. Pls advise.

my requirements:
VALID
(numbers and one dot only)
0.1 (anything starting with 0, must follow by a dot and then number)
1.1234567890 (max. 10 decimal places)

NOT VALID
blank/spaces
0
0.
0.0
00.0
0.0.0
01
integers
+0.1 (no plus signs)
-0.1 (no minus signs)
.1
01.1
1.
0.1e38 (no exponential)

**Solutions:**

```
/^(?=.*[1-9])(?!0\d)([0-9]{1,10})(\.[0-9]{1,10})$/
```

Comment: So you haven't found a solution and now you want us to do your work for free?

Comment: Check out `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`.

Comment: @Jack: do you realize that you proposed OP to *start thinking*? How dare you?!

Comment: Hi Zerkms, so sorry if my question is causing problems to you. i think  the freelancer website is more suitable for you and hopefully this site continues to open for those who needs or willingly to offer advise.

Comment: Please see the help regarding the editing tools to get some help to better format your question. Also you only list requirements, but you do not formulate a programming question out of it. Where is your example that demonstrates your issue? Where are the example values in code that proof that your current solutions does (yet) not work. And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply this:

```
if (($num = filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)) !== false) {
    echo "Yay $num is a float!\n";
}
```

Comment: you have answers in regexr for my preg_match ?

Comment: @user1884324 No, that's too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $str, $matches);
```